# extjs возможность редактировать только одну строку

Tags: javascript

Задача следующая.

При редактирование одной строки, все остальные строки надо сделать неактивными, то есть нельзя их было редактировать, до момента нажатия кнопок "Сохранить" или "Отмена".

Я ссылаюсь на использования слушателя с beforeedit. Слушаем какая строка colIdx была отредактирована и блокируем все остальные пока не сохраним или отменим.
Вопрос в следующем, как заблокировать остальные ячейки и оставить для редактирование только одну строку.

```
 listeners: {
    beforeedit: function (editor, e, eOpts) {},
 }
```